# ERROR ITMS-9000 when trying to upload to iStore

Tags: ios, firemonkey-fm3

I am struggling to upload my app to the iOS store. My most recent error is: ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle 'myAppName' for executable 'Payload/myAppName.app/myAppName'. " at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZltmpsSoftwareAssetPackage)

I do not even know where to start looking for this issue.

Comment: Have you signed your code? Did you use the correct signing certificate?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.  Will you be able to see it in the plist file?

Comment: The signature is not part of the plist file. Since you are not using Xcode, I think you should look at your particular documentation for how to code sign your apps for the Apple store in the Borland IDE.